# Installed 4GB ram but only showing 2GB ram detected

Tags: windows-7, memory

I had a 2GB ram installed in my desktop PC. Now I fixed one more 2GB ram in slot 2. Then when I started the computer It still shows in System properties as Installed memory: 2GB. I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit

However, In CPU-Z, it shows Memory size as 4GBytes. I can't get whats the problem. Pls help.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit OS

Comment: Its 32 bit Windows 7

Comment: That's completely normal in 32 bit if you have a graphics card that have 2GB of Video RAM.

Comment: How much VRAM have you allocated to your iGPU?

Comment: how to find that?

Answer (score -3):

you have to reinstall windows 64 bit , 32 bit os support only 2GB MAX 
though it is tottaly fine to keep useing the system, its harmless

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct. Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit supports 4GB of physical memory ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)).

Comment: Usable should be around 3.5GB with 4GB installed, even with a 32-bit OS installed.

Comment: I agree , my bad its 4GB MAX according to math 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 bytes = 4,096 MB = 4GB

Comment: so he can patch the system useing "PatchPae2" or simply reinstall a 64 bit  os